# Python Pandas DataFrame format() not updating df value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

When attempting to update the format of a column which contains floats or strings, the column values only update for some input files and not others.

Here is the code:

```
    try:
        print('{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.iat[0,1]))
        cell_counts.iat[0,1] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.iat[0,1])
        print(cell_counts.iat[0,1])
    except ValueError:
        cell_counts.iat[0,1] = cell_counts.iat[0,1]

    for x in range(0,8):
        try:
            cell_counts.iat[x,2] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.iat[x,2])
        except ValueError:
            cell_counts.iat[x,2] = cell_counts.iat[x,2]
    
    for x in range(0,8):
        try:
            cell_counts.iat[x,5] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.iat[x,5])
        except ValueError:
            cell_counts.iat[x,5] = cell_counts.iat[x,5]

    try:
        cell_counts.at[0,'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.at[0,'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'])
        cell_counts.at[4,'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.at[4,'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'])
    except ValueError:
        cell_counts.at[0,'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'] = cell_counts.at[0,'Average Cells (Dead or Live)']
        cell_counts.at[4,'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'] = cell_counts.at[4,'Average Cells (Dead or Live)']


    try:
        cell_counts.at[0,'Standard Deviation'] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.at[0,'Standard Deviation'])
        cell_counts.at[4,'Standard Deviation'] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.at[4,'Standard Deviation'])
    except ValueError:
        cell_counts.at[0,'Standard Deviation'] = cell_counts.at[0,'Standard Deviation']
        cell_counts.at[4,'Standard Deviation'] = cell_counts.at[4,'Standard Deviation']

    try:
        cell_counts.at[0,'Calculated Cell Suspension'] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.at[0,'Calculated Cell Suspension'])
        cell_counts.at[4,'Calculated Cell Suspension'] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.at[4,'Calculated Cell Suspension'])
    except ValueError:
        cell_counts.at[0,'Calculated Cell Suspension'] = cell_counts.at[0,'Calculated Cell Suspension']
        cell_counts.at[4,'Calculated Cell Suspension'] = cell_counts.at[4,'Calculated Cell Suspension']

    try:
        cell_counts.at[0,'Cell Recovery'] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.at[0,'Cell Recovery'])
        cell_counts.at[4,'Cell Recovery'] = '{:.2e}'.format(cell_counts.at[4,'Cell Recovery'])
    except ValueError:
        cell_counts.at[0,'Cell Recovery'] = cell_counts.at[0,'Cell Recovery']
        cell_counts.at[4,'Cell Recovery'] = cell_counts.at[4,'Cell Recovery']
```

The formatting string is correct, when checking it with a print statement it formats correctly and even works for some files. Here is one of the outputs:

Here is the [image: Output]

The formatting works for some of the columns but not others. At the top of the screenshot we can see that the formatting does what we want but the value is not updated after storing at the desired location. I know that some use iat and some us at, I am trying everything I can. Is this a situation where I am updating a view/copy of the dataframe?

[image: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvRtI.png)] is the output using different input datafiles. The formatting behaves as expected. I have also tried using if isinstance instead of try/except with the same results.

Any help is appreciated. I will also note that I am clearly not a pro at this.

EDIT:
After attempting the suggestion by Serge below, I am still getting the same results:

```
def format_to_scientific(value):
    try:
        return '{:.2e}'.format(float(value))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return value


for col_index in [1,2,5]:
    for row_index in range(0,8):
        cell_counts.iat[row_index,col_index] = format_to_scientific(cell_counts.iat[row_index,col_index])

target_cells = [
    (0, 'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'),
    (4, 'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'),
    (0, 'Standard Deviation'),
    (4, 'Standard Deviation'),
    (0, 'Calculated Cell Suspension'),
    (4, 'Calculated Cell Suspension'),
    (0, 'Cell Recovery'),
    (4, 'Cell Recovery')
]
for row_index, col_name in target_cells:
    cell_counts.at[row_index, col_name] = format_to_scientific(cell_counts.at[row_index, col_name])
```

[image: Output]
The columns in the beginning are not formatted while the end columns are.

Checking where we are going wrong:

```
    for col_index in [1,2,5]:
    for row_index in range(0,8):
        return_value = format_to_scientific(cell_counts.iat[row_index,col_index])
        print(f'Formatted value:{return_value}')
        cell_counts.iat[row_index,col_index] = return_value
        print(cell_counts.iat[row_index,col_index])
```

[image: Output 2 with prints] [image: Dataframe output] The formatting works but after assignment the dataframe values have not been updated.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert your numeric data columns to strings?  You should do the formatting just in the printing.  And what exactly to you think that the `x=x` type statements are going to do?  Assigning the value in a variable to itself doesn't do anything.

Comment: I would like the values to be displayed in scientific notation. As far as I understand it the statements should set the formatting for the value being passed and store it to the same location. I do not know what you mean by do the formatting in the printing. This set of code is the last piece before the dataframes are returned.

Comment: I think you are getting ValueError exceptions because some of your values are already strings.  Since they are not numbers they can't be formatted.  You would need to parse them to numbers and then format them.  I still think actually converting the data in your dataframe to strings (making them useless numerically) is not what you want to do.  How are you printing your output?

Comment: Yes, some of them will raise ValueErrors, the try/except block handles it. The issue is that the assignment isn't taking correctly. I think it might be due to pandas editing a copy of the dataframe instead of view, but I am not 100% sure since the exact same assignment statements work further along. It is ok for the values to be non-numerical. At this point in the script the dataframes are returned and then outputted into an excel file.  The values are recorded onto paper forms  and scientific notation makes them easier to read.

Comment: Your except blocks do nothing.  `x = x` never does anything.  But if the field is already a strong then it won't get reformatted as you want it to.  I suspect that is the cause of your problem.  I still think you are attacking this wrong.  Your exported excel file isn't going to have numbers in the cells.  You would be better off expecting real numbers and applying the formatting in the Excel file.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. You have already mentioned the except block and the formatting. None of these are issues like I have stated. The exported files are for reporting and are not used for further processing. I have posed the solution below. The try/except block does not update the values for columns that have no value errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the try/except block didn't want to update any columns that had no exceptions when testing row by row. This is interesting behavior to me and still quite does not make sense. First try to format the entire column using map(). If that doesn't work go back to formatting row by row.

```
for col_index in ['Average Cells per Replicate', 'Standard dev per Replicate', 'Included Average Cells/Replicate']:
    try:
        viability_out[col_index] = viability_out[col_index].map('{:.2e}'.format)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        for row_index in range(0,8):
            viability_out.at[row_index,col_index] = format_to_scientific(viability_out.at[row_index,col_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a function to do this. Here is an example based on your code. Modify it to adapt to what you want to do.

```
import pandas as pd


def format_to_scientific(value):
    try:
        return '{:.2e}'.format(float(value))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return value

for col_index in [2, 5]:  
    for row_index in range(8): 
        cell_counts.iat[row_index, col_index] = format_to_scientific(cell_counts.iat[row_index, col_index])

target_cells = [
    (0, 'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'),
    (4, 'Average Cells (Dead or Live)'),
    (0, 'Standard Deviation'),
    (4, 'Standard Deviation'),
    (0, 'Calculated Cell Suspension'),
    (4, 'Calculated Cell Suspension'),
    (0, 'Cell Recovery'),
    (4, 'Cell Recovery')
]

for row_index, col_name in target_cells:
    cell_counts.at[row_index, col_name] = format_to_scientific(cell_counts.at[row_index, col_name])
```

Here is how to apply this. here is a test dataframe

```
data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'Column2': [1.2e3, 3.4e4, 5.6e5, 7.8e6, 9.0e1, 1.1e2, 1.2e3, 1.3e4],
    'Column3': [2.3e3, 4.5e4, 6.7e5, 8.9e6, 1.0e2, 1.2e2, 1.3e3, 1.4e4],
    'Column5': [np.nan, 3.2, 'abc', 4.5e6, 5.6, 7.8, 'xyz', 9.0],
    'Average Cells (Dead or Live)': [2.1e5, 3.2e5, np.nan, 'text', 4.3e5, 5.4e5, 6.5e5, 7.6e5],
    'Standard Deviation': [1.1e2, 2.2e3, 3.3e4, 4.4e5, 5.5e6, 6.6e7, 7.7e8, 8.8e9],
    'Calculated Cell Suspension': [1.23, 2.34, 3.45, 'error', 5.67, 6.78, 7.89, 8.90],
    'Cell Recovery': [11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 44.4, 55.5, 66.6, 77.7, 88.8]
}

cell_counts = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and applying the function

```
for row_index, col_name in target_cells:
    cell_counts.at[row_index, col_name] = format_to_scientific(cell_counts.at[row_index, col_name])
```

returns:

```
   ID    Column2   Column3    Column5 Average Cells (Dead or Live)  \
0   1     1200.0  2.30e+03        NaN                     2.10e+05   
1   2    34000.0  4.50e+04        3.2                     320000.0   
2   3   560000.0  6.70e+05        abc                          NaN   
3   4  7800000.0  8.90e+06  4500000.0                         text   
4   5       90.0  1.00e+02        5.6                     4.30e+05   
5   6      110.0  1.20e+02        7.8                     540000.0   
6   7     1200.0  1.30e+03        xyz                     650000.0   
7   8    13000.0  1.40e+04        9.0                     760000.0   

  Standard Deviation Calculated Cell Suspension Cell Recovery  
0           1.10e+02                   1.23e+00      1.11e+01  
1           2.20e+03                       2.34          22.2  
2           3.30e+04                       3.45          33.3  
3           4.40e+05                      error          44.4  
4           5.50e+06                   5.67e+00      5.55e+01  
5           6.60e+07                       6.78          66.6  
6           7.70e+08                       7.89          77.7  
7           8.80e+09                        8.9          88.8
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will give this a shot later today. I am still unclear on why my solution is not working. Your solution still stores the formatted value into the dataframe at the specified index.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion. After trying the result is still the same. The first few columns of the dataframe do not save the formatted values.